# My firestore account has A LOT of reads. How can I monitore from where?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

My page is quite small it has around 300-1000 visits each day. But at some point I started to accumulate HUGE firestore read requests:

[image]

Till the 8th date it was somewhere around 50K each day. I am pushing new code all the time so I'm not sure what I did. Looking at the page I don't see anything out of ordinary. Is there some sort of log in google or firestore I could look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase documentation indicates that each time you create a project, it also creates a project in Google Cloud Platform, therefore you can track daily Cloud Firestore usage like writes, deletes, etc. This usage information is shown in the GCP's console in the App Engine Quotas page .You can see more details in the link. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage#google-cloud-platform-console

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to track the origin of reads.  What you're looking at now is the best indicator you have available.

Bear in mind that the Firebase and Cloud consoles show updates to documents in real time, and each document update costs a read.  If you leave the console open on a busy collection, it will rack up reads.

Comment: The writes are really low, just couple hundred each day. So this is just from reading data

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying that the console charges you to read documents, even realtime updates.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing documents from the dashboard will also result in reads. So will cloud functions and queries. While debugging an app I had a logging mechanism creating documents in a collection in Firestore and simply opening that collection would cause thousands of reads.